# No permission granted even after adding in manifest and via java in android

Tags: android, admob

I was trying to test simple `Admob` in android so i used below code and when i run app no ad's appear so when i check app permission it shows **No permission requested**

i have added

1. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in androidManifest
2. Also used [Tedpermission](https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPermission), And ted show `Permission Granted` on toast.

My question is why i don't see any ad's in my app?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sanoj.admobtest" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

granting permission via [TedPermission](https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPermission)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btShow;
    AdView adView1,adView2;
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        PermissionListener permissionlistener = new PermissionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionGranted() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionDenied(List<String> deniedPermissions) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied\n" + deniedPermissions.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        };
        TedPermission.with(this)
                .setPermissionListener(permissionlistener)
                .setDeniedMessage("If you reject permission,you can not use this service\n\nPlease turn on permissions at [Setting] > [Permission]")
                .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)
                .check();

        btShow = findViewById(R.id.bt_show);
        adView1 = findViewById(R.id.ad_view1);
        adView2 = findViewById(R.id.ad_view2);

        MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-2471429062443535~8344634230");

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView1.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView2.loadAd(adRequest);

        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-2471429062443535/3691073350");
        interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        btShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bt_show"
        android:text="Show Ad"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ad_view1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2471429062443535/8153062545"
        >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ad_view2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2471429062443535/8144844752"
        >

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can see only dangerous permissions there. And you are not using any from that category. Check your ads implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Permission won't be listed in **Permissions Section**. It's a normal permission that will be granted since it's listed in the **manifest file**.

Permission sections only include dangerous permission (i.e. Location, Storage, etc...). However, *Internet permission* isn't dangerous permission it's ***normal permission***.

Check [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#dangerous-permission-prompt) to know more about dangerous permissions.

Maybe your problem related to your apiKey, or unitId.

Comment: what chang should i do to show test ads, in my code?

Comment: Explore this link to replace your unit Ids with the test ones.

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

Comment: is there anyother way to get `testDeviceIds` because my logcat doesn't work.